# Beistrich bei mehreren Verben / "und" im Nebensatz?

Tags: punctuation

Ist die Beistrichsetzung in diesem Satz korrekt oder muss man nach "was Wert hat" einen Beistrich setzen?

> Bewahren, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet.

---

Dass man vor Beginn des Nebensatzes ein Komma setzen muss, war mir klar. Meine Frage war, ob man nach "was Wert" hat ebenfalls eines setzen muss. Der Satz ist Teil eines längeren Textes, den ich korrigieren soll, und da stand: Bewahren, was Wert hat, und Nutzen stiftet. Meiner Meinung nach sollte das zweite Komma entfernt werden, da es sich um zwei durch "und" verbundene Nebensätze handelt. Ich habe die Thematik gegoogelt aber dazu nichts gefunden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ein "und" bringt normalerweise zwei gleichartige Dinge in Verbindung:

Das Gras ist grün und nass.

("und" verbindet "grün" und "nass", kein Beistrich nötig)

Ich gehe nach Hause und trinke ein Bier.

(Implzites Subjekt "ich" im zweiten Hauptsatz, kein Beistrich nötig, da wir zwei Hauptsätze haben).

Der Hund, der den Brei gestohlen und ihn danach vergraben hat, ist schon wieder da.

(Impliziter Relativsatz "der ihn danach ...", das "und" verbindet zwei gleichartige Nebensätze, kein Beistrich nötig).

Ich erwarte den Hund, der immer wieder in unseren Garten kommt, und möchte ihm einen Knochen geben.

Hier haben wir links vom "und" einen Relativsatz und rechts davon einen Hauptsatz. Der Beistrich ist hier sehr zu empfehlen und hilft dem Leser zu verstehen, dass das "und" an den anfänglichen Hauptsatz "Ich erwarte den Hund" anknüpft, und nicht an den Relativsatz.

Answer (score 2):

Anmerkung: Da der Fragesteller den in der Grammatik für österreichisches Deutsch üblichen Begriff »Beistrich« verwendet hat, werde ich das auch in meiner Antwort tun. In der Grammatik des deutschen Deutsch wäre dafür der Begriff *»Komma«* üblich.

---

Das ist kein vollständiger korrekter Satz sondern entweder eine Ellipse, oder ein Befehl mit falsch gebeugtem Verb.

**a) Ellipse**
Eine Ellipse ist ein verkürzter Satz, dem Elemente fehlen, die eigentlich notwendig wären um einen vollständigen Satz zu ergeben, die aber leicht vom Hörer oder Leser erraten werden können, und aus diesem Grund fehlen dürfen. Eine mögliche vollständige Version wäre dieser Satz:

> Wir müssen das bewahren, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet.

In dem vollständigen Satz hat das Wort *»wir«* die Funktion des Subjekts, und das Modalverb *»müssen«* und das Vollverb im Infintiv *»bewahren«* bilden zusammen das Prädikat.

Das Verb *»bewahren«* verlangt ein Akkusativobjekt (*Wen* oder was bewahren wir?) und dieses Akkusativobjekt ist in meiner Version des ganzen Satzes durch das Demonstrativpronomen *»das«* realisiert. Der Teil hinter dem Beistrich ist ein Relativsatz, der das Akkusativobjekt näher beschreibt. Er könnte auch direkt hinter dem beschriebenen Objekt stehen:

> Wir müssen das, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet, bewahren.

Auf jeden Fall muss dieser Relativsatz durch Beistriche vom Hauptsatz getrennt werden. Wenn er, wie im zweiten Beispiel, in den Hauptsatz eingeschoben ist, müssen das zwei Beistriche sein (einer vorne, einer hinten), ansonsten ist es eben nur einer.

Wenn man den Relativsatz nicht einschiebt, sondern hinten im Nachfeld anhängt, kann man sogar das Akkusativobjekt weglassen:

> Wir müssen bewahren, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet.

<sup>(Natürlich ist auch *»Wir müssen, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet, bewahren«* möglich, aber das ist dann schon ein Stück weit weg von der Alltagssprache und wird daher selten so formuliert.)</sup>

Dann beschriebt der Relativsatz rein formal gar nichts mehr und wird selbst auf der semantischen Ebene zu einer Art Quasi-Objekt, ist aber rein syntaktisch immer noch ein Relativsatz, der mit einem Beistrich vom Hauptsatz abgetrennt werden muss.

Wenn man den Hauptsatz durch Weglassen des Subjektes und des Modalverbs auf ein einzelnes Wort verkürzt (nämlich auf das infinitive Verb *»bewahren«*) ändert sich an der Funktion des Relativsatzes nur wenig.

Der Relativsatz selbst enthält ein Relativpronomen (*»was«*) und eine Aufzählung mit 2 Elementen.

- Aufzählung mit 1 Element (eigentlich: keine Aufzählung)

  > ..., was Wert hat.
- Aufzählung mit 2 Elementen

  > ..., was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet.
- Aufzählung mit 3 Elementen

  > ..., was Wert hat, Nutzen stiftet und glücklich macht.
- Aufzählung mit 4 Elementen

  > ..., was Wert hat, Nutzen stiftet, glücklich macht und notwendig ist.

Wie bei jeder Aufzählung müssen zwischen allen Elementen der Aufzählung Beistriche stehen. Davon ausgenommen ist die Stelle zwischen dem vorletzten und dem letzten Element. Hier kann entweder ein Beistrich oder eine Konjunktion (*»und«* oder *»oder«*) stehen, aber nicht beides zugleich. Üblicherweise zieht man an dieser Stelle die Konjunktion dem Beistrich vor, und es gilt als besserer Stil, die Konjunktion zu verwenden. Aber es ist nicht erlaubt, Beistrich und Konjunktion zugleich zu verwenden.

**b) Befehl mit fehlerhaftem Verb**

Man lässt einen Buchstaben weg und hat einen grammatisch einwandfreien Befehl:

> Bewahre, was Wert hat und Nutzen stiftet!

Befehle in der Du-Form brauchen kein Subjekt, und das oben über das imaginäre Akkusativobjekt *»das«* und den sich darauf beziehenden Relativsatz gesagt wurde, gilt auch hier, inklusive der Notwendigkeit, einen Beistrich zu setzen.